# Iteration over a list in a Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe `df` as this one:

```
                                                  my_list
Index                                                                
0                                               [81310, 81800]
1                                                      [82160]
2            [75001, 75002, 75003, 75004, 75005, 75006, 750...
3                                                      [95190]
4                                               [38170, 38180]
5                                                      [95240]
6                                                      [71150]
7                                                      [62520]
```

I have a list named `code` with at least one element.

```
code = ['75008', '75015']
```

I want to create another column in my `DataFrame` named `my_min`, containing the minimum absolute difference between each element of the list `code` and the list from `df.my_list`.

Here are the commands I tried :

```
df.loc[:, 'my_list'] = min([abs(int(x)-int(y)) for x in code for y in df.loc[:, 'my_list'].str[:]])
>>> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

#or

df.loc[:, 'my_list'] = min([abs(int(x)-int(y)) for x in code for y in df.loc[:, 'my_list']])
>>> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

#or

df.loc[:, 'my_list'] = min([abs(int(x)-int(y)) for x in code for y in df.loc[:, 'my_list'].tolist()])
>>> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

#or

df.loc[:, 'my_list'] = min([abs(int(x)-int(y)) for x in code for y in z for z in df.loc[:, 'my_list'].str[:]])
>>> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment

#or

df.loc[:, 'my_list'] = min([abs(int(x)-int(y)) for x in code for y in z for z in df.loc[:, 'my_list']])
>>> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment

#or

df.loc[:, 'my_list'] = min([abs(int(x)-int(y)) for x in code for y in z for z in df.loc[:, 'my_list'].tolist()])
>>> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this with a list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_list':[[81310, 81800],[82160]]})

code = ['75008', '75015']

pd.DataFrame({'my_min':[min([abs(int(i) - j) for i in code for j in x]) 
              for x in df.my_list]})
```

returns

```
   my_min
0    6295
1    7145
```

You could also use `pd.Series.apply` instead of the outer list, for example:

`df.my_list.apply(lambda x: min([abs(int(i) - j) for i in code for j in x]) )`

Answer (score 1):

Write a helper: `def find_min(lst):` -- it is clear you know how to do that. The helper will consult a global named `code`.

Then apply it:

```
df['my_min'] = df.my_list.apply(find_min)
```

The advantage of breaking out a helper
is you can write separate unit tests for it.

If you prefer to avoid globals,
you will find `partial` quite helpful.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Answer (score 0):

If you have pandas `0.25+` you can use `explode` and combine with `np.min`:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_list':
                  [[81310, 81800], [82160], [75001,75002]]})
code = ['75008', '75015']

# concatenate the lists into one series
s = df.my_list.explode()

# convert `code` into np.array
code = np.array(code, dtype=int)

# this is the output series
pd.Series(np.min(np.abs(s.values[:,None] - code),axis=1), 
          index=s.index).min(level=0)
```

Output:

```
0    6295
1    7145
2       6
dtype: int64
```